# What does probability $\rightarrow ~1$ mean in this context?

Tags: probability

I wish to find a upper bound for the number of consecutive tails seen in $t$ tosses of a fair coin. My question says to show with probability $\rightarrow ~1$ the highest number of consecutive tails has an upper bound given by $(1+e)log_2t$ for all $e>0$.

Let $R_t$ be the largest number of consecutive tails in $t$ fair coin tosses.

So far I have shown $P(R_t \geq (1+e)log_2t) \rightarrow0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ so I think this implies that $R_t<(1+e)log_2t$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$. (Is this correct?).

But I am unsure on what it means when the question asks "show with probability $\rightarrow ~1$" Does this mean I need to show that $R_t \rightarrow (1+e)log_2t$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$? (That is the value of $R_t$ actually approaches this upperbound as $t$ gets large?) If so how would I do that?

Comment: I think it means to show that $\mathbb{P}\Big(R_t \leq (1+e)\log_2(t)\Big) \to 1$ as $t \to \infty$, which is what you've shown using complementary probability. I'm just not quite sure about the part 'for all $e>0$'.